# Frontend jsp form not binding to model: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, forms, hibernate, jsp

I have a Spring/Hibernate/Maven application, with jsp in the frontend.

This is my form:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="newCase">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Project Description:</td>
            <td><form:input path="projectDescription" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Project Number:</td>
            <td><form:input path="projectNumber" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <input type="submit" class="orange_black" value="SAVE" />
        </tr>
</form:form>
```

And form tags are working (on other pages I have similar forms).

And its model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="case")
public class CaseModel {

    private String projectDescription;

    private String projectNumber;


    ...getters and setters...toString()..
}
```

And the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")

public class CaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newCase", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getNewCase(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("newCase", new CaseModel());
        return "newCase";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newCase", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createNewCase(@Valid @ModelAttribute("newCase") CaseModel newCase, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

        System.out.println(newCase.toString());       

        return "redirect:/dashboard";

    }
}
```

Application was running completely normal, everything was regular. Adding CaseModel hasn't changed anything. But when I added `<form:form>` element and binded it with the model, I started receiving error:

```
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project.model.entities.CaseModel
```

Are there any ideas about what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

**EDIT: THIS IS PART OF THE LOG**

```
Severe:   WebModule[/LawyersApplication]StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/alphaandomega/pdfannotationseditor/model/entities/CaseModel
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:402)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:332)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:908)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1583)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5946)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
```

...

Comment: Alpha,Where you are adding element and binding to which property of your model class?

Comment: Have you declared CaseModel as a Bean?

Comment: In the GET method of my Controller class, I set the model attribute to "newCase" and return the page. Then this form uses that as a model. On submit, I retrieve POST method and print input values

Comment: Yes I understand what your saying but if you've not declared the CaseModel as a bean then that would explain the binding issue, because it depends on the CaseModel Bean to get and set values from the form.

Comment: @smoggers I haven't, later this will be mapped with hibernate to the specific database entity...

Answer (score 0):

Add the annotation @component in the  and @componentscan in the model class. Hope it would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is my config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"com.project.configuration"})
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class HibernateConfiguration {
...
    @Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{
        "com.project.model"});
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
    }
   ...
    }
```

com.project.model package was divided (by me, two days ago, during refactoring) in two sub packages, and they were both named in `sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(..)`
For some reason, this is why any new classes weren't mapped. After merging model sub packages into one, everything continued to working smoothly again.

Thank you all for suggestions!